# USB type-C / type-A computer to computer link?

Tags: windows, usb, transfer, data-transfer

I have a computer (a MSI laptop) which has a "SS" (so USB 3.0, I assume) USB Type-C female connector, and I want to use this port to transfer data to a standard USB Type-A (EDIT: 3.0, also) female connector on another computer (a generic Dell workstation).

But none of my computers detect the other one... Any ideas?

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/q/795053

Comment: I'm not sure I understand which part of this link I am supposed to look into, since the user asking the question is looking for a networking connection?